Created a resource to help solve a problem I was having in a lab. Can I publish it?
I had to complete a lab for school assessing the accuracy and precision of calculating a triangular prism’s moment of inertia using a trifilar pendulum. When I wanted to compare my lab results to theoretical data, I couldn't find the moment of inertia for a regular triangular prism around the desired centroidal axis anywhere online. So, I derived it from the expression:
$$I=3\cdot\int_{0}^{h}\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{3}}\int_{0}^{\left(\frac{r}{2\sin\left(\theta-\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)}\right)}\rho r'^{3}dr'\ d\theta\ dh'$$
Which simplifies right down to:
$$\frac{1}{4}mr^{2}$$
I've also come up with a generalized equation for a regular n-sided polygonal prism:
$$I(n)=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+2}{6}mr^2$$
Which agrees with the previous form at $n=3$ and the equation for a cylinder (which can be easily found online) at $n=\infty$:
$$I(3)=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)+2}{6}mr^2=\frac{1}{4}mr^2$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}I(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+2}{6}mr^2=\frac{1}{2}mr^2$$
I wanted to share the full derivation as well as a table of a couple common regular polygonal prisms and their corresponding inertias about that axis, since it is a resource I would have appreciated when completing this lab. However, I'm unsure over which medium this might be published (are there journals that publish such resources for undergraduate/high school level physics?), or whether it is worth "publishing" to begin with (i.e. the derivation is trivial and my initial struggle with deriving the moment is not common). Any thoughts or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated :)

It seems like the type of thing that would be put in a handbook or textbook, but you'd have to know people who are editing one. I'd say add it to a personal engineer's reference manual that you can compile both for your own futures reference and anyone you want to share it with. It's common to gain a lot of useful facts like these over the course of a career or period of study.

What kind of triangular prism? A right triangular prism, an equilateral triangular prism? I saw a derivation for a right triangular prism online so I'm assuming this is a regular equilateral triangular prism.

Yes, it was an equilateral triangular prism should have clarified.

Also this link shows that the MoI of a regular n-gon already exists online, Moment of inertia for an n-sided regular polygon.

What is does your symbol $r$ stand for? The length of a side? The distance from center to an edge?

It looks like your $r$ is probably distance from center to a vertex, so $r=\frac{L}{\sqrt{3}}$, where $L$ is the length of a side of the triangle. So the equivalent result is also here: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FormulaRepository/resources/Moment-of-Inertia-of-a-Triangular-Plate

From the quoted page using $a=b=c=L$ and $L = \sqrt{3}r$ we see $I=\frac{m}{36}(3L^2)=9mr^2/36 = mr^2/4$

Wow I didn't know this community was so active, thanks for the quick responses! Checking it out this derivation does exist on that post (where they use a instead of r for the circumradius), and the result lines up on the Wolfram. Apreciate the info!

Not that it's not neat to have results ready to write down, certainly having tables like this is handy. Have you tried finding the perpendicular moments of inertia of the prism through the other axes?

Yes I have similar derivations for the other axes although I have seen those more commonly on other sites. I have this for prisms with "holes" of circumrardius $r_i$ as well, with obvoiusly much larger expansions. Do you think it would still be useful to provide/publish such a table somewhere? I want to know if it is worth generating images for these cases etc.
